# How to have an array with no pair of elements closer by a distance

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I want to remove elements from a numpy vector that are closer than a distance d. (I don't want any pair in the array or list that have a smaller distance between them than d but don't want to remove the pair completely otherwise.

for example if my array is:

> ```
> array([[0.       ],
>        [0.9486833],
>        [1.8973666],
>        [2.8460498],
>        [0.9486833]], dtype=float32)
> ```

All I need is to remove either the element with the index 1 or 4 not both of them.

I also need the indices of the elements from the original array that remain in the latent one.

Since the original array is in tensorflow 2.0, I will be happier if conversion to numpy is not needed like above. Because of speed also I prefer not to use another package and stay with numpy or scipy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution, using only a list. Note that this modifies the original list, so if you want to keep the original, copy.deepcopy it.

```
THRESHOLD = 0.1    
def wrangle(l):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        for j in range(len(l)-1, i, -1):
            if abs(l[i] - l[j]) < THRESHOLD:
                l.pop(j)
```

Comment: thanks do you also know a way to know the indeces of the elements that remain?

Comment: Not easily, since the list changes as you chew through it.

Answer (score 1):

using `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0.       ],
              [0.9486833],
              [1.8973666],
              [2.8460498],
              [0.9486833]])

threshold = 1.0
# The indices of the items smaller than a certain threshold, but larger than 0.
smaller_than = np.flatnonzero(np.logical_and(a < threshold, a > 0))
# Get the first index smaller than threshold
first_index = smaller_than[0]

# Recreate array without this index (bit cumbersome)
new_array = a[np.arange(len(a)) != first_index]
```

I'm pretty sure this is really easy to recreate in `tensorflow`, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is really only 1-d you can flatten it and do something like this:

```
a=tf.constant(np.array([[0.       ],
                        [0.9486833],
                        [1.8973666],
                        [2.8460498],
                        [0.9486833]], dtype=np.float32))

d = 0.1

flat_a = tf.reshape(a,[-1])  # flatten



a1 = tf.expand_dims(flat_a, 1)
a2 = tf.expand_dims(flat_a, 0)
distance_map = tf.math.abs(a1-a2)
too_small = tf.cast(tf.math.less(dist_map, d), tf.int32)  
# 1 at indices i,j if the distance between elements at i and j is less than d, 0 otherwise

upper_triangular_part = tf.linalg.band_part(too_small, 0, -1) - tf.linalg.band_part(too_small, 0,0)

remove = tf.reduce_sum(upper_triangular_part, axis=0)
remove = tf.cast(tf.math.greater(remove, 0), tf.float32)
# 1. at indices where the element should be removed, 0. otherwise

output = flat_a - remove * flat_a
```

You can access the indices through the remove tensor. If you need the extra dimension you can just use tf.expand_dims at the end of this.